# Optimized process for receiving data packets during heavy network load

Tags: c++, tcp, network-programming, tcpclient

I am writing a client-server application(TCP protocol) in C++.
I have possibility where a client can receive data from multiple servers.
To tackle this, I have created a socket connections list.

In a loop, on each socket, I perform following:

- try to receive data on this on socket
- put this in a buffer
- process buffer data
- clear buffer
- perform same steps for next socket

Now in my design, initially I had created a common buffer for all connections. But I am suggested that in case of heavy load on network, it may happen that received telegram is not complete telegram, it may be a part of a telegram. so to make a telegram complete I will have to wait for next iteration for same socket and even clubbing/identifying telegrams will be a complex process.

To handle this scenario, one solution may be to provide dedicated buffer for each connection.

Can anybody suggest more optimized/better solution to avoid creating dedicated buffer for each connection?

Comment: Take A look at Boost Asio http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html so you don't have to re-invent the wheel.  In a general sense though if you need to be able to hold instances of partial data you need to have a buffer for that.  Also note the network stack will buffer TCP data for you so depending on your exact requirements that may be good enough.

Comment: The "not receiving the complete telegram" issue is not unique to heavy loads. You'll have that issue on light loads as well. TCP socket streams receive partial data all the time - it's the nature of TCP (via segmentation, fragmentation, burps on the network, etc..). In any case, you'll always want to loop on each socket until you receive the complete message.

Comment: @selbie: great point, and equally: if you send two messages they may be received by a single call to `recv` or `read`.  Ultimately, TCP is a *byte stream* protocol with flow control, and you must be ready for blocking and/or partial sends and partial/merged receives.

Comment: As I understand from all comments and answers, buffer per connection is onlu way out for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you're serious about this you'd use a thread per socket, each with its own buffer, possibly doing the processing too or passing it to a connection-specific processing thread, but you could also send all the incoming data to a single "work" queue if it needs to be done serially for some reason.

If you must use a single thread, then you must use a buffer per connection.  TCP implements a kind of flow control which means the sending side may not even be allowed to send more of a message until the receiving side has consumed enough.  If you're concerned about memory usage you could delete connection-specific buffers that have been fully processed and only re-create them when an incomplete message is detected, but normally pages that aren't recently accessed will be swapped out in tight memory situations so there's little harm in retaining the memory - as long as your (virtual) address space is plentiful: time and fragmentation associated with repeated dynamic memory allocations and deallocations may be worse than the peak memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you want to process the entire message/telegram only when you have it all in memory at once, then a dedicated receive-buffer for each TCP connection will be the only way to go.  Unless you are very limited in the amount of RAM you have available, or the incoming messages are very large, this should not be a problem.  (if it is a problem, consider ways to make the messages smaller; e.g. by breaking each message up into a series of smaller messages that can be be processed in series instead)